# Phpmailer not sending email to gmail

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

<sub>I'm making an OTP verification mail for my registration form, and I'm using [phpmailer](/questions/tagged/phpmailer) to send a verification email to Gmail. but unfortunately, it won't send. I watched a tutorial about making an OTP verification form using phpmailer, still it wont work</sub>

here are my codes for the registration form.

```
<?php
    
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['SESSION_EMAIL'])) {
        header("Location: welcome.php");
        die();
    }

    //Load Composer's autoloader
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    include 'config.php';
    $msg = "";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, md5($_POST['password']));
        $confirm_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, md5($_POST['confirm-password']));
        $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, md5(rand()));

        if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='{$email}'")) > 0) {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>{$email} - This email address has been already exists.</div>";
        } else {
            if ($password === $confirm_password) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, code) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$email}', '{$password}', '{$code}')";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                if ($result) {
                    echo "<div style='display: none;'>";
                    //Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
                    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

                    try {
                        //Server settings
                        $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
                        $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
                        $mail->Host       = "tls://smtp.gmail.com";                   //Set the SMTP server to send through
                        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
                        $mail->Username   = 'tk23@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
                        $mail->Password   = '12345678';                               //SMTP password
                        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
                        $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`
                                 

                        //Recipients
                        $mail->setFrom('tk23@gmail.com','Mailer');
                        $mail->addAddress($email);

                        //Content
                        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
                        $mail->Subject = 'no reply';
                        $mail->Body    = 'Here is the verification link <b><a href="http://localhost/login/?verification='.$code.'">http://localhost/login/?verification='.$code.'</a></b>';

                        $mail->send();
                        echo 'Message has been sent';
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
                    }
                    echo "</div>";
                    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-info'>We've send a verification link on your email address.</div>";
                } else {
                    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Something wrong went.</div>";
                }
            } else {
                $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Password and Confirm Password do not match</div>";
            }
        }
    }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">

<head>
    <title>Login Form - Brave Coder</title>
    <!-- Meta tag Keywords -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="keywords"
        content="Login Form" />
    <!-- //Meta tag Keywords -->

    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--/Style-CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/otp.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <!--//Style-CSS -->

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/af562a2a63.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- form section start -->
    <section class="w3l-mockup-form">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- /form -->
            <div class="workinghny-form-grid">
                <div class="main-mockup">
                    <div class="alert-close">
                        <span class="fa fa-close"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3l_form align-self">
                        <div class="left_grid_info">
                            <img src="images/image2.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-wthree">
                        <h2>Register Now</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
                        <?php echo $msg; ?>
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            <input type="text" class="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { echo $name; } ?>" required>
                            <input type="email" class="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { echo $email; } ?>" required>
                            <input type="password" class="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" required>
                            <input type="password" class="confirm-password" name="confirm-password" placeholder="Enter Your Confirm Password" required>
                            <button name="submit" class="btn" type="submit">Register</button>
                        </form>
                        <div class="social-icons">
                            <p>Have an account! <a href="guest_login.php">Login</a>.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- //form -->
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- //form section start -->

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (c) {
            $('.alert-close').on('click', function (c) {
                $('.main-mockup').fadeOut('slow', function (c) {
                    $('.main-mockup').remove();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Somebody told me to replace my port and host to TLS 587, still it wont work. can anybody help me with this problem? thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "won't work"? What debugging have you done? Have you verified there are no PHP errors? Do you see the `echo 'Message has been sent';` message? Or something else? What does PHPMailer's detailed debug output show?

Comment: N.B. From a glance at the code I don't expect that the `host` value should contain the protocol (`tls://`) as well...normally it should just be purely the hostname. The protocol should be SMTP anyway.

Comment: Also since it's Gmail, have you set up an App Password instead of trying to authenticate with the default google account password? This is required for all apps which try to connect to Gmail but can't use 2-factor authentication.

Comment: `Somebody told me`...on what basis? https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps doesn't suggest that. Nor does any other Gmail SMTP example I can find online, when using SSL.

Comment: If you wanted to try TLS on 587 I expect you'd need to use the ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS option instead of ENCRYPTION_SMTPS

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data. mysqli_real_escape_string is obsolete and doesn't guard against everything.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: Also, please don't store passwords using the obsolete, insecure md5 algorithm - that is another security risk. Learn about PHP's built-in, up-to-date, secure [password hashing and verification functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead. See also [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bit of a mess, and if you had followed [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) you'd have had more luck. PHPMailer *does* support setting the `SMTPSecure` mode and the port number from the `Host` property, however, it's much clearer to set those properties explicitly. You're running into a problem with it because you have conflicting settings. Do this instead:

```php
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = 'tk23@gmail.com';
$mail->Password   = '12345678';
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
$mail->Port       = 465;
```

[The troubleshooting guide explains all about the various different encryption options](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#using-encryption), and which ports they work on. These days, SMTPS on port 465 is the preferred option.

Note that you are still likely to run into problems because gmail no longer allows simple password-based auth; you need to look into [switching to XOAUTH2](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2).